# Is it possible to call multiple handler methods on a single submit in atg?

Tags: atg

Consider I have one submit button. On clicking submit, it should call both `handleAddData()` and `handleInsertData()`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can call multiple handlers on single submit, using a component atg.search.formhandlers.MultipleSubmitHelper,

we have to configure - MultipleSubmitHelper component by setting its queryFormHandlers property to an array

Example- queryFormHandlers=/atg/search/formhandlers/QueryFormHandler1,
/atg/search/formhandlers/QueryFormHandler2

Answer (score 0):

A `<dsp:input>` tag can only be bound to a single element in ATG. That said, you can have 3 handle methods, one which calls both the others (eg. `handleCallAddInsertData`) and bind your tag to this, still leaving you with the original `handleAddData` and `handleInsertData`. Alternatively you can submit your form via Javascript which will in turn call both handle methods.

If, however you need to call them 'both' you probably have a flaw in your design.